Search values in multiple sheets in google sheet
I need a formula for column C in the 'main' sheet of a Google Sheet. The formula should search for each email listed in column A within the sheet named in the corresponding cell of column B. If a match is found, the formula should output the value from column D in the same row as the matching email.
Example:
The value in cell C1 is 7 because it's found by searching for the email 'john@gmail.com' within the sheet named 'A01'.

Here is what we have in sheet 'A01'.

Thank for any suggestion.


You may try:
=vlookup(A1,indirect(B1&"!B:D"),3,)


Why B:D? I didn't quite get it.

this visual representation should help

How about if the email john@gmail.com was in cell A2 (instead of B2 as in the example) in sheet A01? Your code woud show NA for the search (in fact it would show 7).

Share a test sheet showcasing your input(s) an expected output(entered manually) so that it gives a clear picture on what is expected.

I just want the following:
Search for the email given in column A of “main” from the sheet whose name is given in column B (of “main”). When found, output the number in column D of the target sheet which is in the same row as the found cell.

Yes, it did not work. The logic I guess would be =vlookup(A1,indirect(B1&"!A:D"),4,)  since there are 4 columns (A to D) in the target sheet. But it showed NA.

Hopefully someone else will pitch in with an alternative solution...
